# How can I open specific ports on a handheld?

Tags: c#, port, windows-ce, handheld, port80

I have struggled and wrangled with this problem on-and-off-and-on again for a good while now: getting my custom app on my handheld device to make REST calls to an app running on the network, or at least, as a start, on the PC to which the handheld is tethered via USB cable.

I actually got this to work for a brief time and then got distracted with other things, I guess, and forgot how I did it, and/or my device's settings got changed, or something.

I came across this clue in some old notes of mine, though:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

*Aha! Once I added 80 and 8080 as ports to allow (but how I did that, I no longer remember), I am now able to successfully call the REST method from the handheld. I'll check the .pcap contents of a successful send and see how this changes what I saw/posted above.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I assume that the allowance of ports needs to be done on the handheld - or is it the PC? Or both? At any rate, as my parenthetic pathetic aside says, I don't remember at all what I did. Does anybody know how these ports can be allowed? Better yet, can it done in code, so that, even if somebody "monkeys with" the device, when the app runs, it will open those ports back up?

### UPDATE

If it's a matter of configuring the Firewall, what do I need to do? I opened Windows Farwall, and it presents me with an embarassment of "riches" (the forest/trees conundrum):

[image]

Is this where I allow ports 80 and 8080, and if so, how exactly?

Comment: The web service needs to be configured for port 80 or 8080, or both. The device can't connect to a port that the web service isn't listening on. After that, you need to make sure that a firewall doesn't prevent connections to your configured port. Firewalls or other port restrictions can exist both on the server box and in any routing devices you use.

Comment: There shouldn't be any routing device, at least when going straight from the handheld to the PC via USB cable, right?

Comment: Correct - so that leaves your service configuration and the service box firewall.

Comment: The REST URLs contain ports embedded within them (such as 21608). Why I need to monkey with 80 and 8080, I don't recall, but something in connection with doing that was the only time I was able to get it to work from the handheld. Via another local app, it works; by adding the URLs to Postman, it works. It's the handheld that is the "bottleneck" somehow.

Comment: In order to troubleshoot/eliminate firewall issues you might want to temporarily turn it off completely. If that does turn out to be an/the issue, there will be an entry under Firewall for the connection attempt where you can configure the (rejected) connection to be allowed going forward, if I recall correctly.